# Scripting for windows

Tags: linux, windows, scripting, batch-file

This is my first time trying scripting and I'm trying to create a small program that does a simple division and mod in a loop, and then calculates the average of the mod results. 
This is what I have tried in Linux .sh, but how could I make it compatible with Windows .bat? Your help is very appreciated.

```
echo "enter first number:"
read first_num
echo “enter second number:”
read second_num
while [ first_num && second_num != 999 ]
do
    if [ second_num != 0 ]; then
        echo "Enter first number:"
        read first_num
        echo"Enter second number:"
        read second_num
        echo first_num "/" second_num "=" $((first_num / second_ num)) >> file.txt
    else
        echo "ERROR. Cannot divide by 0. Enter another number:"    
    fi
done
if [ first_num == 999 || second_num == 999 ]; then
   echo "You have exited the loop."
fi

#Mod 5 of numbers 1-100:
for i in {1...100}
do
    result=$((i % 5))
    echo i + "%5=" + result >> file.txt
done

#Average of results:
int sum=0
for (( i=1; i<101; i=i+1 ))
do    
    sum=sum+$((i % 5))
    average=$((sum/100))
    echo average
    echo average >> file.txt
done
```

Comment: `SET /P` receives input; `SET /A` does math; `IF` and `FOR` are available; `CALL` lets you fake a code block. What kind of answer did you have in mind when asking?

Comment: Use a real scripting language. For example bash or sh. Or even better, Python. But cmd.exe sucks. Stack Overflow is not a porting service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "enter first number:"
read first_num
```

becomes 
    set /p first_num="Enter first number "

```
while [ first_num && second_num != 999 ]
```

don't have a WHILE - have to wire it. Think clubs and rocks.

```
:loop
if %first_num%==999 goto endloop
if %second_num%==999 goto endloop

...

goto loop
:endloop
```

`:name` is a label, `%var%` retrieves contents of `var` - is always a string enclose in quotes if the string includes spaces.

```
if [ second_num != 0 ]; then
```

translated is

```
if NOT %second_num%==0 ( ...things... ) else (...other things...)
```

or, of course

```
if %second_num%==0 ( ...other things... ) else (...things...)
```

Quirk: (one of many) : the first open-parenthesis MUST occur on the same physical line as the `IF` and the `ELSE` must be on the same physical line as the `)` of the on-true statemet sequence.

```
echo first_num "/" second_num "=" $((first_num / second_ num)) >> file.txt
```

Can't do a calculation in an echo

```
set /a result=(first_num / second_ num)
```

OR

```
set /a result=(%first_num% / %second_ num%)
```

`SET /A` applies the results of an arithmetic expression - later addition and more C-like semantics

then

```
echo %first_num% / %second_num% = %result% >> file.txt
```

purely stringing the elements together.

Next there is a small problem. During the parsing process, any %var% is replaced by its PARSE-TIME value and **THEN** the line is executed. Consequently, the `ECHO` line above would show the values as they stood when the IF statement was entered, not after the calculations.

Two cures:

You can use `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELATEDEXPANSION` to switch the interpreter mode. In DELAYEDEXPANSION mode, `!var!` may be used to retrieve the RUN-TIME value of `var`. A `SETLOCAL` is terminated by an `ENDLOCAL` or by reaching END-OF-FILE in the same context. Any environment changes after a `SETLOCAL` are undone by an `ENDLOCAL` which is why it's often performed immediately after the `@echo off` - keeps the environment clean.

second cure is to use a subroutine. `CALL :SUB` (the colon means 'internal subroutine - start label is in this batchfile'. Omitting it means 'this is an external executable') The CALL creates a new context, copying the then-existing environment variables, so

```
:sub
echo %first_num% / %second_num% = %result% >> file.txt
goto :eof
```

will display the variables from the environment as it stood when a `CALL :SUB` was executed.
Note that `GOTO :EOF` (the colon is `REQUIRED` means 'go to physical end-of-file' - the label `EOF` should not be declared...

(beware also flow-through to subroutines normally placed at the end of batchfiles. A judicious `GOTO :EOF` ensures that flow-through does not occur...

```
#Mod 5 of numbers 1-100:
```

The comments indicator is officially `REM`

```
rem Mod 5 of numbers 1-100:
```

BUT

```
::Mod 5 of numbers 1-100:
```

is often used as it's easier to type BUT since it's actually a misuse of a label, it is actually a label, and labels can't be used in a compound statement, you you can't use it within the parentheses of `IF ... (...) else (...)` or `FOR...DO (...)`

```
for i in {1...100}
```

becomes

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,100) do (
```

The metavariable `%%i` IS case-sensitive and a single character. in a `FOR /L` the elements are (start,step,end) - see `FOR /?` from the prompt (or generally `command /?` from the prompt) for docco...

```
result=$((i % 5))
```

becomes

```
set /a result=%%i %% 5
```

`/a` because the RHS is an arithmetic expression to be evaluated; %% 5 because `%` escapes `%`, the space is irrelevant and the processor needs to know that the MOD operator `%` is being used, not `%5` (the fifth command-line argument)

```
int sum=0
```

No such thing as types; all environment variables are strings and only interpreted as integers by the `set /a` statement

so - that's about all there is to it...

Answer (score 0):

Hope you're looking for this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
> file.txt type nul
:loopInput
echo enter first number:
set /p first_num=
echo enter second number:
set /p second_num=

if !first_num! neq 0 (
    if !second_num! neq 999 (
        if !second_num! equ 0 (
            echo ERROR. Cannot divide by 0. Enter another number:
            goto loopInput
        )
        goto loopDiv
    )
)
goto :skipDiv

:loopDiv
set /a division=first_num/second_num

>> file.txt echo !first_num! / !second_num! = !division!
goto loopInput

:skipDiv
echo You have exited the div loop.

>> file.txt echo Mod 5 of numbers 1-100:
for /l %%a in (1,1,100) do (
    set /a mod=%%a%%5
    >> file.txt echo %%a %% 5 = !mod!
)

set sum=0
for /l %%a in (1,1,100) do (
    set /a sum+=%%a%%5
)
set /a average=sum/100
>> file.txt echo Average of results: !average!
```